# Mongoid has_and_belongs_to_many without '_ids' suffix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid4

In the following example:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands
end
```

The objects are stored like this:

```
# The band document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9"),
  "tag_ids" : [ ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f2") ]
}

# The tag document.
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f2"),
  "band_ids" : [ ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9") ]
}
```

Is possible to rename the field `tag_ids` to `tags` and `band_ids` to `bands`? Thanks

Comment: I've an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to use a specific foreign key name:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, foreign_key: "bands"
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands, foreign_key: "tags"
end
```

But avoid to use foreign key names that may conflict with your available relations.